# Automatically multiply an array with another array in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to calculate a set of metrics break by month by multiplying the total with the weight of each month, show it on an separated row, and also remove the row with zero value.
Something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHO4J.png)

[image]

You can find the sample on this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nYlzJdL1g07m_dfkpNi1KyIo5yaMOQDUFOLk9PJZRKI/edit?usp=sharing

I do appreciate of your help guys.
Thank you

I've tried to use an Arrayformula(B4:C4*toCol(E4:I4)).
It worked well for the very first row, but I stuck on automatically applying it to the rest of the dataset.

Please help me to find the way.

---

Updated question 18 Jul

Hi TheWizEd

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nYlzJdL1g07m_dfkpNi1KyIo5yaMOQDUFOLk9PJZRKI/edit?usp=sharing

I've updated the dataset I have on the file above, let's me explain my way:
I got a raw data as in sheet **My raw dataset**,
then I take out all the things I need to sheet **Process Data**,
then applying your code as below:

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Process Data");
    let sheet1 = spread.getSheetByName("Final Result");

    // get the range of values in Sample Data starting with A4
    let range = sheet.getRange("A3").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);  // get number of rows
    range = range.offset(1,0,range.getNumRows(),33);

    console.log(range.getA1Notation());

    // get the values
    let values = range.getValues();

    // get the first row which contains the months
    let months = values.shift();
    months = months.slice(21);
    console.log(months);
    let rows = [];
    values.forEach( row => {
        let client = row.shift();
        let brand = row.shift();
        let category = row.shift();
        let platform = row.shift();
        let vendor = row.shift();
        let adType = row.shift();
        let kpiType = row.shift();
        let ageGender = row.shift();
        let geo = row.shift();
        let location = row.shift();
        let targetingType = row.shift();
        let detailedTargeting = row.shift();
        let start = row.shift();
        let end = row.shift();
        let spending = row.shift();
        let imp = row.shift();
        let view = row.shift();
        let click = row.shift();
        let conv = row.shift();
        row.shift(); // remove blank
        let i = 0;
        row.forEach( month => {
            if( month > 0 ) {
              rows.push(
                 [client,
                  brand,
                  category,
                  platform,
                  vendor,
                  adType,
                  kpiType,
                  ageGender,
                  geo,
                  location,
                  targetingType,
                  detailedTargeting,
                  months[i],
                 (spending*row[i]).toFixed(2),
                 (imp*row[i]).toFixed(0),
                 (view*row[i]).toFixed(0),
                 (click*row[i]).toFixed(0),
                 (conv*row[i]).toFixed(0)])
            }
            i++;
          }
        );
      }
    );

    // put values in result table
    sheet1.getRange("A3").offset(0,0,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Everything works perfectly, but I think my way is a little bit redundant, and it has a better way to do it.

Sorry I'm a non-tech guys, please help me to explain what you would do, I will try to google it then..

Thank you so much TheWizEd.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    // get the range of values in Sample Data starting with A4
    let range = sheet.getRange("A3").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);  // get number of rows
    range = range.offset(0,0,range.getNumRows(),9);
    console.log(range.getA1Notation());
    // get the values
    let values = range.getValues();
    // get the first row which contains the months
    let months = values.shift();
    months = months.slice(4);
    console.log(months);
    let rows = [];
    values.forEach( row => {
        let camp = row.shift();
        let cost = row.shift();
        let quant = row.shift();
        row.shift(); // remove blank
        let i = 0;
        row.forEach( month => {
            if( month !== "" ) {
              rows.push([camp,months[i],(cost*row[i]).toFixed(2),(quant*row[i]).toFixed(2)])
            }
            i++;
          }
        );
      }
    );
    // put values in result table
    sheet.getRange("L4").offset(0,0,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Range.getDataRegion()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdataregiondimension)
- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [Number.toFixed()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you @TheWizEd, it worked properly in my case. But when I have a dataset of multiple dimensions, for example: Campaign name, age, gender, location,.. let's say up to 15 dimensions, if I declare all of them, it works well too, but if I just declare some of them (eg. 10 of 15 dimensions), the results was broken.  Do you have any workaround on this? Thank you very much for your support, it helps me alot.

Comment: Without seeing the actual data I can't tell you how to change it.  But just know that all the data is in the array `values`.  You simply need to adjust the array index to the right column.

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd, I've updated my question as above, please help me on this. I really appreciate your support.